# How to pass javascript variables from index.html to index.jsp?

Tags: html, jsp, url-rewriting, parameter-passing

I am able to obtain clients country using api in javascript and ajax.

But now I want to send the value to index.**jsp**.

how do I rewrite the url or send using *index.jsp?country=someinfo*  ?

Is there any method to send parameters via url and get that variable value in index.jsp?

And will the index.**jsp** clash with index.**html** ???

Answer (score 0):

index.jsp **will not** clash with index.html, they are different files.

You can send parameters by URL as you describe `index.jsp?country=someinfo`

But you can also send it using `<form action = "index.jsp" method = "GET">` , inside the form each input as `<input name="country" value="someinfo"/>` will be sent also the parameters, See [more details](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm).